# Gin not finding @Provides method

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

Here is my Gin module:

```
public class FooGinModule extends AbstractGinModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    ...

    bind(ActivityManager.class).asEagerSingleton();

    ...
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public ActivityManager getActivityManager(EventBus eventBus, SimplePanel display,
      ActivityMapper activityMapper) {
    final ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);
    activityManager.setDisplay(display);
    return activityManager;
  }

}
```

When I try to gwt-compile, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] No @Inject or default constructor found for class
>   com.google.gwt.activity.shared.ActivityManager

Am I specifying the `@Provides` method wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the explicit binding, and in fact I think it will override the `@Provides` method. I don't know of a nice way to use `asEagerSingleton()` with a `@Provides` method, instead consider a `Provider<T>` implementation.

```
bind(ActivityManager.class)
    .toProvider(MyActivityManagerProvider.class)
    .asEagerSingleton();
```

Looking at the actual stuff you are generating/wiring, I find it useful to actually `@Inject` the `ActivityManager` instance to the parent of the `SimplePanel` (or whatever you are using as the display), and calling `setDisplay` there instead. At least to me, this makes it easier to replace the display or change it, as it is part of that block of code instead of part of the module. It also removes the need to create an eager singleton.